# Store data into a many to many table relashionchip Laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel, many-to-many, laravel-5.3

I need to create a method to write data to a relationship table. And I'm sending the data via get, and I need to store them in my table. Below is the code I wrote to you the moment.

```
public function store(Request $request){

        $campanha = Campanha::find($request->campanha);

        foreach ($request->chksintese as $key => $value) {
            $campanha->sinteses()->attach($value);

        }

        return redirect('sintese-campanha');
    }
```

My request comes this way:

```
array:2 [▼
  "campanha" => "26"
  "chksintese" => array:5 [▼
    0 => "92"
    1 => "86"
    2 => "1"
    3 => "9"
    4 => "13"
  ]
]
```

In my models I have the relationship methods:

```
public function sinteses(){
         return $this->belongsToMany(Sintese::class);
}
```

And

```
public function campanhas(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Campanha::class);
}
```

I know this is pretty basic, but I'm starting now on laravel. I hope someone can help.

I`m gettin an error:

```
QueryException in Connection.php line 769:
SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR: relation "campanha_sintese" does not exist
LINE 1: insert into "campanha_sintese" ("campanha_id", "sintese_id")...
^ (SQL: insert into "campanha_sintese" ("campanha_id", "sintese_id") values (31, 13))
```

My migration code for my relashionship table

```
 public function up()
{
    Schema::create('callcenter.campanha_sintese', function(Blueprint $table) {

        $table->integer('sintese_id')->unsigned;
        $table->foreign('sintese_id')->references('cod_sintese_conversa')->on('crm.sintese_conversa');

        $table->integer('campanha_id')->unsigned;
        $table->foreign('campanha_id')->references('id_campanha')->on('callcenter.campanha_new');

        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Comment: ok so what is your question? the provided code does not work? what error do you get? you may update your question

Comment: Yes, my code doesn`t work and i receave this message: SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR: relation "campanha_sintese" does not exist
LINE 1: insert into "campanha_sintese" ("campanha_id", "sintese_id")...
^ (SQL: insert into "campanha_sintese" ("campanha_id", "sintese_id") values (31, 13))

Comment: You have to create the pivot table "campanha_sintese" with the specified fields

Comment: Ok, I already have the table, however, Laravel identifies the table "campanha_sintese" and I need it to be "callcenter.campanha_sintese" because my database has several Schemas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass your table to your relationships so Laravel know where to look for the relationship.

```
public function sinteses(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Sintese::class, "callcenter.campanha_sintese");
}

public function campanhas(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Campanha::class, "callcenter.campanha_sintese");
}
```

You may also need to add primary and foreign key in your relationship. Check the guide on Laravel how to add those keys. Pretty easy.